# Cannot use Composer 1.6.3 version of composer with fabric 1.2, v0.20 or higher is required

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

when i update to version 0.20 everything is deprecate but on linux i'm recommended to be like this, Cannot use Composer 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17 version of composer with fabric 1.2, v0.20 or higher is required

Comment: Hyperledger Composer stopped being developed a while ago and as such is not only deprecated but end of life.I highly recommend that you look at using fabric 2.2 instead. Also it looks like you have installed another application called `composer` as there is no hyperledger composer 1.6.3